# VueJs fetching questions in Quiz app

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to build a simple quiz app. it has some questions which are in the database. I am fetching those using AXIOS request. 
I am doing something like this :

```
var app = new Vue({
        el:"#app",
            data:{
                currentQuestion:0,
                question:{}
            },
            methods:{
                    next:function(){
                        this.currentQuestion+=1;
                        this.loadQuest();
                    } , 
                    loadQuest:function(){
                         axios.get('/questions').then((response)=>{
                        //console.log(response.data[this.currentQuestion]);
                        this.question = response.data[this.currentQuestion];
                       })
                    }
            },
            mounted(){
                    this.loadQuest();
                },     
    });
```

Here you can see whenever I click next question button loadQuest() is called and a request is sent to the server. Is there any way not to send request on every next button click instead just increment the currentQuestion variable and load next question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make 'questions' an Array (not an Object)
2. Get all the questions at the start
3. The computed value 'question' will watch on a change on 'currentQuestion' automatically and update the value accordingly

```
    const app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        currentQuestion: 0,
        questions: [],
      },
      mounted() {
        axios.get('/questions').then((response) => {
          // console.log(response.data[this.currentQuestion]);
          this.questions = response.data
        })
      },
      methods: {
        next () {
          this.currentQuestion += 1
        }
      },
      computed: {
        question () {
          return this.questions.length ? this.questions[this.currentQuestion] : {}
        }
      }
    })
```

Comment: Thank you for answer @sebestian. the code is working fine but in console having 2 warnings. `The computed property "question" is already defined in data.` and `[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'question' of undefined"`

Comment: any idea? why am I having this warning?

Comment: I have updated the code, the first error should removed. How are you displaying the 'question'? `{{question}}` ?

Comment: <h4 v-text="questions[currentQuestion].question"></h4> i have column in database called question

Comment: oops! I have made a small mistake that's why it was throwing an error.displaying question like this : <h4 v-text="question.question"></h4>  solved the problem . Thanks, man!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how many questions you have, but you could just fetch all question with a request on load, and store them in a `questions: {}` object declared in your data. And on click just fetch the question directly from the object. Code example below:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el:"#app",
        data:{
            currentQuestion:0,
            questions:{},
            question:{}
        },
        methods:{
                next:function(){
                    this.loadNextQuest();
                    this.currentQuestion+=1;
                } , 
                loadQuest:function(){
                     axios.get('/questions').then((response)=>{
                    //console.log(response.data[this.currentQuestion]);
                    this.questions = response.data;
                   })
                },
                loadNextQuest:function(){
                    this.question = this.questions[this.currentQuestion];
                }
        },
        mounted(){
                this.loadQuest();
            },     
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works fine for me. but in the console having following error.    app.js:32494 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'question' of undefined"

Comment: in HTML, I am calling these values like this `<h4 v-text="questions[currentQuestion].question"></h4>`  in database column name is question